# Django - Increase a model field based on another model

Tags: django, python-3.x

I have a model called Product and a model called Stock.
The model Product has a field called 'stock_current' that should show the current stock of an product and in model Stock has a field called 'quantity'. I'm looking for a way to when register one entry in model Stock, the field 'stock current' of Product's model get the current number and increase with the field 'quantity' of Stock model.

I'm totally lost since i am a beginner with django.

## #model

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    cost = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    price = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)

    stock_min = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    stock_current = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    stock_control = models.BooleanField(default=True)


class Stock (models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, blank=False, null=False)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(blank=False, null=False)
```

## #views

```
def stock_add(request, stock_id=None):

if stock_id:
    v_stock = Stock.objects.get(pk=stock_id)
else:
    v_stock = None

if request.method == 'POST':
    form_stock = StockaddForm(request.POST or None, instance=v_stock)

    if form_stock.is_valid():
        resp = form_stock.save()
        if resp:
            messages.success(request, "Product has been registred !")
            return redirect('/')
else:
    form_stock = StockaddForm(instance=v_stock)

context_dict = {}
context_dict['form_stock'] = form_stock

return render(request, 'admin_panel/register/stock_add.html', context_dict)
```

Until now i just know the way how to register a stock.
The question is how to add the value of 'quantity' field to 'stock_current' field of a object in the Product model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
resp.product.stock_current += resp.quantity
resp.product.save()
```